# How to fetch Column Names from Table?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to fetch column names form Table in Oracle. But I am not getting Column Names.
I used Many query's, And Find may query's in Stack overflow But I didn't get answer.

I used below query's:

```
1.  SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='TABLE_NAME';

2.  SELECT COLUMN_NAME from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='TABLE_NAME';
```

But Out Put is

```
 no row selected
```

What is the problem here. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

both of the queries are correct, just the thing which can cause this problem is that ,maybe you did n't write your table name with `capital letters` you must do something like this:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS 
where TABLE_NAME = UPPER('TABLE_NAME');
```

OR

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS 
where TABLE_NAME = UPPER('TABLE_NAME');
```

Comment: Thank you @Hamidreza I have given lower case. that's why it's not worked .Now it's fine Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT column_name
FROM   all_tab_cols
WHERE  upper(table_name) = 'TABLE_NAME'
       AND owner = ' || +_db+ || '
       AND column_name NOT IN ( 'password', 'version', 'id' )
```

or

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = UPPER('TABLE_NAME');
```

Comment: yes it's exists. When executed "Select * from TableName;" It showing result. But When I am trying to retrieve column name it's showing No Row Selected

Comment: is it possible you created the table with double brackets ? try changing the filter to `upper(table_name) = 'TABLE_NAME'`

Comment: @codegeek:- This is working fine for me. As suggested by haki please try to change the column name to upper letters

Comment: @codegeek:- You are welcome. I have updated my answer as well. So that it helps others in future!

Answer (score 0):

I hope This query would help yu out

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME  (schema_id) + '.' + t.name AS 'Table Name'    
FROM sys.tables t 
INNER JOIN sys.columns c
ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE c.name like '%hmy%
ORDER BY 'Table Name'
```